# in generation of fractal mountain how to perturb the location/point in openGL

Tags: opengl

I'm reading a book on OpenGL, "Interactive Computer Graphics" by Edward Angel. A question says a variation on sierpinski gasket produces fractal mountain and to do so we need to **perturb** the location before division. 
Can anyone please explain how to perform this perturb operation since I am newbie to openGL. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone has already answered this here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539703/fractal-mountains-using-sierpinski-gasket-in-opengl

Comment: Thanks. but i didn't get how to add noise to the generated point. I tried adding random value to the generated point but that didn't help me much.

Comment: @user2971489: Noise == Random